# Simplifying a cosine triple angle expansion

Tags: trigonometry, binomial-theorem

The problem is express $\dfrac{1+\cos 3\theta}{1+\cos \theta }$ in terms of increasing powers of $\sin \theta.$

I have derived upto
$1-8\sin^2 \dfrac{\theta}{2}+16\sin^4 \dfrac{\theta}{2}$, but am unaware how to proceed further. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I'm gonna format this for you but I'm not sure if that's meant to be a $cos^3(\theta)$ or a $\cos(3\theta),$ can you confirm? Also, can you show how you proceeded to get to that attempt?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: it was cosine of 3*theta. I used the double angle formula for the original equation, simplifying into (cos(1.5 theta) / cos (0.5 theta))^2 Then used the expansion for cube of cosine and simplified further. Thanks for editing @StephenDonovan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation can be transformed first into:

$$(2\cos(\theta)-1)^2$$

which we further can transform using the relationship $\cos(\theta)=1-2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}$ to:

$$(2(1-2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2})-1)^2=(1-4\sin\frac{\theta}{2})^2$$

The half-angle identity for Sine is $sin\frac{\theta}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos{\theta}}{2}}$, which unfortunatelly does not allow us for reducing the above-given term further.

Comment: Yes, I got that expression. The problem is, can the equation be expressed only in $(sin(\theta/2) )$ or can it be expressed in $sin(\theta)$ alone?

Comment: I highly doubt that it is possible.

Comment: Ok no problem. Thanks for your input.